# I am trying to make a survey of answers to questions and cannot add each response to the responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, state

I am trying to capture the users responses to survey questions. Each individual state is reflecting the changes, But when I try to add them to the array of responses, it just never works. I have tried everything I found online to no avail... help please!!!

Data looks like this after the await runs
[{key:"1", colWidth:"8", questionType:'Multiple Choice', text: 'What is your favorite color?',choices: [{'distractorID':1,'distractorText':'Red'},{'distractorID':2,'distractorText':'Green'},{'distractorID':3,'distractorText':'Blue'},
{'distractorID':4,'distractorText':'Orange'},{'distractorID':5,'distractorText':'Gold'},
{'distractorID':6,'distractorText':'Pink'}]},{key:"2", colWidth:"6", questionType:'Rating', text: 'on a scale of 1 to 10 how good was this program?', choices:"", numStars: 10},
{key:"3", colWidth:"6", questionType:'Text', text: 'What is your favorite part of the day?', choices:"", numStars: 0},{key:"4", colWidth:"8", questionType:'Multiple Choice', text: 'Do you enjoy good food?', choices: [{'distractorID':7,'distractorText':'Yes'},{'distractorID':8,'distractorText':'No'}],"numStars":0},{key:"5", colWidth:"8", questionType:'Multiple Choice', text: 'I like broccoli?', choices: [{'distractorID':9,'distractorText':'False'},'distractorID':10,'distractorText':'True'}],"numStars":0},{key:"6", colWidth:"8", questionType:'Multiple Choice', text: 'I would do this again', choices [{'distractorID':11,'distractorText':'False'},'distractorID':12,'distractorText':'True'}],"numStars":0}]

```
        import './App.css';
        import  { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
        import TextBox from "./components/TextBox";
        import StarRating from './components/StarRating';
        import Question from './components/Question';
        import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
        import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
        
        
        function App(props) 
          {
          const orgID = 29;
        
          const userID = 106580;
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          const sid = /[^/]*$/.exec(document.location)[0];
        
          const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('pt-br').split( '/' ).reverse( ).join( '-' );
        
          const [ questions, setQuestions ] = useState([]);
        
          const [ responses, setResponses] = useState([]);
        
          const [ theresponse, setTheresponse] = useState (
              {
              responseID:0,
              surveyId:parseInt(sid),
              questionID: 0,
              distractorID:"",
              responseText: 0 ,
              userID: parseInt(userID),
              orgID: parseInt(orgID),
              lastEditor: parseInt(userID),
              lastEditDate: today
              }
            );
        
         function displayResults() 
             {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(responses));
             }
        
          // update the state for a rating change
          function handleRatingChange(rating, questionid) {
            //set the individual state  
            setTheresponse(prevState => 
              ({ ...prevState,
                  responseID:0,
                  surveyId:parseInt(sid),
                  questionID: parseInt(questionid),
                  distractorID:"",
                  responseText: parseInt(rating) ,
                  userID: parseInt(userID),
                  orgID: parseInt(orgID),
                  lastEditor: parseInt(userID),
                  lastEditDate: today,
              }));
              //set the group state 
            setResponses(prevState => ({ ...prevState,
                ...theresponse,
              }));
            }
        
          function handleAnswerChange(questionid, answer, key) 
            {
            setTheresponse(prevState => ({ ...prevState,
              responseID:0,
              questionID: questionid,
              distractorID:parseInt(key),
              responseText: answer,
              }));
            //set the group state 
            setResponses(prevState => ({ ...prevState,
                ...theresponse,
              }));
            }
          
          // update the state for the text field being changed
          function handleTextChange(qid, answer) 
            {
            //set the individual state
            setTheresponse(prevState => ({ ...prevState,
                responseID:0,
                questionID: parseInt(qid),
                distractorID:"",
                responseText: answer,
              }));
            //set the group state 
            setResponses(prevState => ({ ...prevState,
                ...theresponse,
              }));
            }
        
            useEffect(() => 
            {
            const fetchData = async () => {
          
              const response = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:5000/getQuestionsForJson/${sid}`);
                 const data = await response.json();
                 //use only 3 sample data
                 setQuestions( data );
              }
          
              // Call the function
              fetchData();
            }, []);
        
        
        
            return (
              <div>
                {questions.map((data) => {
                  switch (data.questionType) {
                    case 'Text':
                      return <TextBox 
                      colWidth={data.colWidth}                    // col-md-{colWidth}
                      key={data.key}                              // questionID
                      question={data.text}                        // questionText
                      onAnswerChange={handleTextChange}           // Selection event
                      />
                    case 'Rating Scale':
                      return <StarRating 
                      colWidth={data.colWidth}                    // col-md-{colWidth}
                      questionid={data.key}                       // questionID
                      key={data.key}                              // questionID
                      question={data.text}                        // questionText
                      numStars={data.numStars}                    // number of stars
                      onRatingChange={handleRatingChange}         // selection event
                      />
                    case 'Multiple Choice':
                      return <Question 
                      colWidth={data.colWidth}                    // col-md-{colWidth}
                      key={data.key}                              // questionID
                      questionType="multiple choice"              // questionType
                      question={data}                             // questionText
                      onAnswerChange={handleAnswerChange}         // Selection Event
                      />
                    default:
                      return <div>Type Not Found</div>
                    }  
                  })}
                  <div className='container col-md-2'>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <button type="button" onClick={displayResults} className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>&nbsp;
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            );
          }
        
        export default App;
```

When I run it the array of responses always only has the last one done I am trying to have an array of responses to the survey questions so that I can submit the once amd either they all make it or they all fail.

Comment: I found the answer. Thank you anyway to the community.